# I am retrieving all the contactlist. However it works fine in iPhone 5 but crashes in iPhone 5s

Tags: ios, contacts

I am retrieving all the contact list. However it woks fine in iPhone 5 but crashes in iPhone 5s.
Please have a look at the below code.

```
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPeople; i++) {

    ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex( allPeople, i );

    NSString *firstName = (__bridge NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty));
    NSString *lastName = (__bridge NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty));

    ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

    for (CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNumbers); i++) {
        NSString *phoneNumber = (__bridge_transfer NSString *) ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, i);
        NSLog(@" name is %@ %@phone:%@",firstName,lastName, phoneNumber);

        if(phoneNumber.length > 0)
        {
            if(firstName.length <=0)
                firstName = @"";
            if(lastName<=0)
                lastName = @"";
            [contactNameArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",firstName,lastName]];


            NSString *formattedPhoneNumber = phoneNumber;

            formattedPhoneNumber = [formattedPhoneNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
            formattedPhoneNumber = [formattedPhoneNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];

            formattedPhoneNumber = [self formatPhoneNumber:formattedPhoneNumber];

            [contactListPhoneArray addObject:formattedPhoneNumber];
            [checkMarkArray addObject:@"no"];
            [registeredTrackArray addObject:@"no"];
        }

        //[contactListPhoneArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",phoneNumber]];
        //[checkMarkArray addObject:@"no"];
    }
```

Comment: for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPeople; i++) - change it to NSInteger.

Comment: What is the crash message? Which line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPeople; i++)
```

- change it to NSInteger.
iphone 5s is on 64bit si you have to use long instead of int. You should use NSInteger

```
#if __LP64__ || (TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED && !TARGET_OS_IPHONE) || TARGET_OS_WIN32 || NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64
typedef long NSInteger;
typedef unsigned long NSUInteger;
#else
typedef int NSInteger;
typedef unsigned int NSUInteger;
#endif
```